# Content Page won't accept parameters

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

I'm going through a basic tutorial to teach you how to have a page accept a parameter through the url for example http://localhost:0000/Movies/edit/"number" where number is any integer and the page would display the integer. My code is:

```
public ActionResult Edit(int i)
    {
        return Content("id=" + i);
    }
```

This tells me that the url contains a null parameter "i" of Non-nullable type "System.Int32" for method "Edit(Int32)".
I know the link is correct because I have another page that doesn't accept variables through the url and that works fine. 
I've watched the tutorial multiple times and can't find any difference between our code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure that the paramter you send is not null , if it is null these because of the default route configuration for your app .
you will find the Route configuration in app_start file in Rout_config.cs

```
public ActionResult Edit(string Id)
{
    return Content("id=" + Id);
}
```

Comment: This worked, I changed the variable "i" to "Id", I didn't realise I had to name the variable the same as in the route config. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The following was written by the question author, [Jack Tyler](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5836688/jack-tyler), in [this revision](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/46324706/2) of the question.

> I change the variable "i" to "Id", I didn't realise I had to name the variable the same as in the route config.

Comment: @Servy: I'll leave your edit, but I have a couple of hundred CW posts from folks whose answer I have moved, and that's too much work for me to do for each one. Personally I think "OP" is clear enough, and the revision number is unnecessary meta-detail that is not of interest to readers wanting answer material. My solution is that if an OP wishes to re-post, then can do so, and I always offer to delete my CW copy.

Comment: If you leave out the author's name, the link to the content, and don't properly indicate that quoted content is a quotation, then you are not only meeting the site's definition of plagiarism, but violating the site's CC-BY-SA licence by not properly attributing content, making it a copyright violation.  If you don't have the time to *appropriately* cite some content, then don't copy the content.  Just deciding to not properly cite content isn't appropriate.

Comment: @Servy: I respectfully disagree, at least for now. I do rather too much editing work as it is, without an additional burden placed upon me! I think my approach at least places the content in the right place, and I have not had a complaint yet (OPs are free to edit in their byline if they wish, of course). However, would you be willing to ask a _Meta_ question on this theme, if it is important to you? I will give way if the community is firmly in agreement.

Comment: You disagree that it's a problem for you to plagiarize content and violate other people's copyright rights?  That's...just not okay.  Again, if you think it's too much of a burden on you to not plagiarize content when copying other people's content then *don't post the content*.  The site's licence and legal page (as well as the help center page on plagiarism) are quite explicit in what is required.

Comment: @Servy: thanks again for your thoughts. If you do post a Meta question on it - and I would warmly welcome it - please ping me.